# How to check pods per node

Tags: kubernetes

I Googled and checked kubernetes docs but couldn't find anywhere.

Basically how can I check that how many pods per node can run in my k8s environment? Which command's output or config file provide this information?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, nodes have limit of 100 pods per node([as mentioned by docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/best-practices/cluster-large/), but looks like in fact this limit is 110 pods per node). You can check pods limit for specific node, by running `kubectl describe node node_name`, which, among other info will return something like this:

```
Capacity:
  cpu:                2
  ephemeral-storage:  81120924Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             4046380Ki
  pods:               110
```